# Google Sheets multiply values in cell by both integer in same cell and number of TRUE in same row

Tags: google-sheets, count, sum, google-sheets-formula, flatten

I have the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(REPT(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A4, " "), 
 "(?:\d+x)?(.+)")&"×", IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A4, " "), "(\d+)x"), 1)*1)), "×"))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

This counts the number of entries in column A, extracting the variable text like `2x` and `1x`, then lists them as unique cells accompanied by a count of each (while ignoring empty cells).

[image]

Now, I'd like to modify this to count associated checkboxes in 3 previous columns, comparing with the unique entries of the original column, as well as comparing the variable number of `2x` and `1x` so that it appropriately assigns the values.

In other words, I want it to turn out like so:

[image]

I've tried to modify the previous formula by adding (what I thought was) an additional range to the second `FLATTEN`.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(REPT(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(D1:D14, " "), 
 "(?:\d+x)?(.+)")&"×", IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(D1:D14, " "), "(\d+)x"), 1)*1)), "×"),
SPLIT(REPT(COUNTIF(A1:A=true,D4:D<>"")*1), "×"))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by count(Col1) DESC label count(Col1)''"))
```

Among many others as I've begun to understand the formula given, I also tried a very roundabout way, first removing the `QUERY` part of the above to separate the Unique Strings into one column, and count into the other:

```
=FLATTEN(REPT(COUNTIF(B1:C=true,D1:D=F1),IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(N4:N56, " "), "(\d+)x"), 1)*1))
```

[image]

None of those worked.

So again, how would I get the following results?

[image]

Comment: This was difficult to word correctly. If anyone has a better idea of wording what I want, please feel free to edit.

Comment: so value in D column counts into F:G summary whenever any of those checkboxes on a given row are checked?

Comment: Hello @player0 , you helped with my question yesterday! Yes, since column D can have variable strings where people put `2x` and `1x`, it needs to be able to determine when to take those into account as well. (A thought I just had: Maybe ignore the checkboxes when `#x` is involved?)

Comment: ok for C38 (3), but why G7 is 5 and not 6, why C55 is 2 not 6?

Comment: I'm equally lost here. But where Mike sees G7 should be 6, I see it should be 7. This all means that the goal (or the data... or both) are not clear.

Comment: So, counting down for G7 in order: 1xG7, 1xG7, 2xG7, 1xG7

Comment: Pressed enter too soon. C55 is 2 because only 2 of those checkboxes are allocated to C55. Perhaps that's the wording I was looking for — Allocation. All the checkboxes measure allocation of what's in Column D. There's only 3 possible "allocations" per row, and some of them could be split between 2 or 3 different letter-number combinations.

Comment: What is the actual goal of this spreadsheet? where is the data coming from? what's it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(""&IFERROR(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF((A1:C15=TRUE)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(D1:D15, "\d+x")), D1:D15, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(D1:D15, "\d+x"), REPT(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(D1:D15, " "), "\d+x(.*)")&"×", 
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(D1:D15, " "), "(\d+)x")*1), ))), "×"))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) DESC label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much again, I'm starting to understand how it works now too.